# Using backstretch.js and blur.js (or similar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background-image

### Update

I have answered the question below, however, it is very laggy and the cross-fade between the images appears stepped. Is there anyone that can advise on how to optimise this?

Maybe I should revert back and use a 'static' image, that is selected at random and use that until the page is refreshed.

---

### Question

I would like to know if it is possible or if someone has a working example to blur a background image (potentially background slide show).

Currently I have the following which loops through 12 images, displaying each for 10 seconds before fading to the next one. I would like to be able to blur the background if possible. In the case where the image needs to be static, I would like it to select an image at random from a pre-defined list.

The below works (I'm including blur.js however that currently doesn't do anything).

I have also selected the css3 tag as I am aware that some css3 properties will produce a blur effect.

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/backstretch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/blur.js"></script>
<script>
$.backstretch([
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1428604467652-115d9d71a7f1",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1428591501234-1ffcb0d6871f",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1423882503395-8571951e45cc",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1422433555807-2559a27433bd",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420819453217-57b6badd9e19",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1414912925664-0c502cc25dde",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/reserve/IPEivX6xSBaiYOukY88V_DSC06462_tonemapped.jpg",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/reserve/fPuLkQNXRUKI6HQ2cMPf_IMG_4761.jpg",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1425136738262-212551713a58",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1425036458755-dc303a604201",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1422640805998-18a4dd89bec2",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/reserve/Ept9mCvnTiahpYXPi9Ej_DSC_0010.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 1000});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mstnorris/tg05oxk0/1/

Comment: Please share what you have tried, perhaps setup a jsfiddle for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

So, while creating a jsfiddle for use to show what I had already done, I was looking for blur.js on cdnjs when I stumbled upon vague.js.

You can find a link to the completed script below, it is very simple and works exactly as I had hoped.

```
$.backstretch([
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1428604467652-115d9d71a7f1",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1428591501234-1ffcb0d6871f",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1423882503395-8571951e45cc",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1422433555807-2559a27433bd",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420819453217-57b6badd9e19",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1414912925664-0c502cc25dde",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/reserve/IPEivX6xSBaiYOukY88V_DSC06462_tonemapped.jpg",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/reserve/fPuLkQNXRUKI6HQ2cMPf_IMG_4761.jpg",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1425136738262-212551713a58",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1425036458755-dc303a604201",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1422640805998-18a4dd89bec2",
    "https://download.unsplash.com/reserve/Ept9mCvnTiahpYXPi9Ej_DSC_0010.jpg"
], {duration: 3000, fade: 1000});

var vague = $('body').Vague({
    intensity:      10,      // Blur Intensity
    forceSVGUrl:    false,   // Force absolute path to the SVG filter,
    // default animation options
    animationOptions: {
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear' // here you can use also custom jQuery easing functions
    }
});

vague.blur();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mstnorris/s0Lbpzuu/2/